# Is there a single word term for doubled amplitude of square wave?

Tags: terminology, square, amplitude

The [IEC60050](https://std.iec.ch/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=103-07-02) (103-07-02) tells that the amplitude is "*maximum value of a scalar **sinusoidal** quantity*". So the peak-to-peak voltage is a doubled amplitude. Is there a single word term for a square wave (or a CMOS single-ended signal) which be equivalent to peak-to-peak voltage or a doubled amplitude?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a square wave is also a "scalar sinusoidal quantity", as it is the sum of a number of sine waves. Either way, in practice, the terms are exactly the same no matter which waveform.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Firstly the IEC60050 emphasizes that the amplitude term can be applied only to sin-wave not to all waveforms. Secondly terms are useful when they facilitate communication. We can measure the energy consumption of our 
apartment in electronvolts for example but it's not convenient. So in this case it does't matter whether a square wave is a sum of sin wave (actually it always does) or not.

Comment: "the amplitude term can be applied only to sin-wave not to all waveforms" I really don't believe that's how you should interpret this information. There are more than one definition of many terms in the same standard, check out [702-04-54](https://std.iec.ch/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=702-04-54) for example.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure whether you are referring to a single ended square wave i.e. a unipolar waveform or a bipolar square wave. The peak values are the same but the RMS value of the bipolar waveform is the same as the peak.